# WPF/C# Algorithm for resizing control using mouse with 8 different resize points?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, resize

Wasn't sure how to title this, but basically I have created a cropping function for cropping images and it looks a bit like this:

[image]

At the moment, the user can move this box (which is actually just a border with several child borders) and draw new ones of any size. What it can't do, is allow the user to resize it after already drawn. It has to be able to resize in each direction you see a small square. For this, the only thing I can think of to do is write a MouseUp, MouseDown, and MouseMove method for each one.

My first question is, can this be simplified so that we can eliminate having to have 24 events for achieving this?

My second question is, if NOT, how would I go about actually resizing it?

My current algorithm would mean resizing the parent border and changing the (x,y) coordinates of this on the canvas, but I would also like to allow the possibility of resizing past the top point.

For example, if the user is resizing up using the bottom-most square, the border would eventually have a zero height, but then continue going in that direction. So essentially, the border would have a fixed top position until the mouse extended beyond that point, then it would have a fixed bottom position as the height increases upward. I tested this with just one square and now it's starting to seem more complicated than it is worth completing.

This is a sample of my current algorithm:

```
private void southCropBorder_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.southCropBorder.CaptureMouse();
}

private void southCropBorder_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.southCropBorder.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}

private void southCropBorder_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) { return; }

    double Y_1 = Canvas.GetTop(this.croppingBorder);
    double Y_2 = e.GetPosition(this.canvas1).Y;

    double Y_3 = Y_2 - Y_1;

    if (Y_3 > 0)
    {
        this.croppingBorder.Height = Y_2 - Y_1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Y_3 != 0)
        {
            Canvas.SetBottom(this.croppingBorder, Y_1);
            this.croppingBorder.Height = Y_3 * -1;
        }
    }
}
```

And then the XAML:

```
<Border x:Name="croppingBorder" Cursor="SizeAll" Panel.ZIndex="1000" Visibility="Hidden" Background="LightGray" Width="0" Height="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Opacity="0.6">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="34*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="34*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="northWestCropBorder" Background="Gray" Panel.ZIndex="1" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10" Height="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="-5,-5,0,0" MouseUp="northWestCropBorder_MouseUp" MouseDown="northWestCropBorder_MouseDown"/>
        <Border x:Name="northCropBorder" Background="Gray" Panel.ZIndex="1" Cursor="SizeNS" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10" Height="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,-5,-5,0" MouseUp="northCropBorder_MouseUp" MouseDown="northCropBorder_MouseDown"/>
        <Border x:Name="northEastCropBorder" Background="Gray" Panel.ZIndex="1" Cursor="SizeNESW" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10" Height="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,-5,-5,0" MouseUp="northEastCropBorder_MouseUp" MouseDown="northEastCropBorder_MouseDown"/>
        <Border x:Name="westCropBorder" Background="Gray" Panel.ZIndex="1" Cursor="SizeWE" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Height="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="-5,0,0,0" MouseUp="westCropBorder_MouseUp" MouseDown="westCropBorder_MouseDown"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="Gray" Panel.ZIndex="1" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="0,0,-5,0"/>
        <Border x:Name="eastCropBorder" Background="Gray" Panel.ZIndex="1" Cursor="SizeWE" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Height="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,-5,0" MouseUp="eastCropBorder_MouseUp" MouseDown="eastCropBorder_MouseDown"/>
        <Border x:Name="southWestCropBorder" Background="Gray" Panel.ZIndex="1" Cursor="SizeNESW" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="10" Height="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,-5,-5" MouseUp="southWestCropBorder_MouseUp" MouseDown="southWestCropBorder_MouseDown"/>
        <Border x:Name="southCropBorder" Background="Gray" Panel.ZIndex="1" Cursor="SizeNS" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="10" Height="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,-5,-5" MouseUp="southCropBorder_MouseUp" MouseDown="southCropBorder_MouseDown" MouseMove="southCropBorder_MouseMove"/>
        <Border x:Name="southEastCropBorder" Background="Gray" Panel.ZIndex="1" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="10" Height="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,-5,-5" MouseUp="southEastCropBorder_MouseUp" MouseDown="southEastCropBorder_MouseDown"/>
        <Image x:Name="croppingSelectionImage" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Stretch="Fill" MouseDown="croppingSelectionImage_MouseDown" MouseMove="croppingSelectionImage_MouseMove"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

At this point, resizing is all fine and dandy until you start trying to extend beyond the initial top position.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**
Ok, so I came across [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771714(v=vs.90).aspx), which really makes more sense. Still pondering how it can be made to move in opposite side directions, as well. I have provided an example image in photoshop to exemplify what I'm trying to acheive:

[image]

Note, how we start at the bottom and move our way up to the top (which is something photoshop can actually do). Will start here and update when I find a fix...

Comment: The relevant code to your case has to include the north. Maybe change the southCorner code to that instead, so we'll see where the problem is.

Comment: Well, when you think about it, southCropBorder would then technically be north and then it would be as though you're resizing up from northCropBorder. This totally makes sense, but now I'm even more boggled as to how it can be achieved this way. Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: consider using `Adorner`, searching for this ***WPF Adorner***, you'll see some result about it as well as some demo to see. It's much easier than implement your own.